# rails assign 10.seconds to a named variable and do calculations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, variables

How would one create a named variable, assign seconds to it, and use it for doing calculations?

```
start_sec = 10.seconds
end_sec = 20.seconds
```

start_sec + end_sec

```
does not return correct values
```

Comment: Returns 30.seconds for me, what are you expecting? Can you just use (10+20).seconds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly solution:

```
start_sec = eval("10.seconds")
end_sec = eval("20.seconds")
start_sec + end_sec
```

Not sure if you mean this.

Comment: thx yes i wanted something like this but coudent figure out how